# Yii2 - model rules 'required' fails

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, rules

I have simple form, which collects: name, city, street and post_code. 
These are rules that I have:

```
return [
    [['city', 'street', 'name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    [['post_code'], 'string', 'max' => 6],
    ['post_code', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^([0-9]{2})(-[0-9]{3})?$/i'],
    [['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'street'] => 'required']
];
```

It returns me error "Illegal offset type" and marks first line to be faulty, but when I comment the last line, it works fine (but of course doesn't require values to be written). What can it be caused by?

Comment: Also I would suggest to put
`[['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'street'], 'trim']` to rules, to trim white space from begining and end of field values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last line should be

```
[['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'street'], 'required']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your last index please change it to

```
 [['name', 'city', 'post_code', 'street'],'required']
```

Comment: Don't add duplicate answers. Kindly remove.

Comment: How's your answer different from Bizley?